# How to load a template from a cron?

Tags: layout, template, cron, html, blocks

I have a new cron job collecting data, working with it and so on.
Now I want to send a mail with a template from inside that cron job.

But first I had to load/render my template file(s).

Therefore I have a new method:

```
private function generatePdf($name, $address, $vatId, $data)
{
    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
    $block = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'mymodule_mail')
        ->setTemplate('mail/default/html/layout.phtml');
    $grid = $block->setChild('product.item', $block);
    $html = $grid->toHtml();

    return $html;
}
```

But everytime I start and debug my cron job the $html variable is empty. Nothing. I can see that $block is from type Mage_Core_Block_Template and that the _template has the correct value. But I can't see any HTML-Code.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
->setPackageName('mymodule') //Name of Package
->setTheme('default'); // Name of theme
```

That helps!

Now I have the problem that I don't know how to set a template for a child?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code you posted, I think you created a block with name `mymodule_mail` that has a child with alias `product.item`, which contains an instance of the `mymodule_mail` block. Instead of referring to the original block, a new block should be created instead. Also, the $grid and $block variables are references to the same object.

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
private function generatePdf($name, $address, $vatId, $data)
{
    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
    $block = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'mymodule_mail')
        ->setTemplate('mail/default/html/layout.phtml');
    $itemBlock = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'product.item')
        ->setTemplate('mail/default/html/layout/item.phtml');
    $block->setChild('product.item', $itemBlock);
    $html = $block->toHtml();

    return $html;
}
```

And to make sure `item.phtml` is shown, the following line should be added to `layout.phtml` at the desired location:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.item') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would love to see @Tipo to post this answer he found. In case you see this, do it on your own and tell me, I'll delete my answer.

Solution:

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
->setPackageName('mymodule') //Name of Package
->setTheme('default'); // Name of theme
```